# Angular radion button ng-model does not work

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I wonder why the code below for radio button does not work. I cannot select any option from the radio buttons. It froze once I click any of the option. I was able to select and does not froze when I remove ng-model.

```
<div class="col-lg-12">
<div ng-repeat="q in getCurrentSectionsQuestion().qs">
    <h2>{{q.q}}</h2>
    <ul ng-if="q.qtype == 'checkbox'">
        <li ng-repeat="option in q.options">
            <input type="{{q.qtype}}" name="{{q.qid}}" ng-value="{{option.selected}}" ng-model="option.selected" ng-change="!option.selected || appendAnswer(q,option.option)"/>
            {{option.option}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul ng-if="q.qtype == 'radio'">
        <li ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
            <input type="{{q.qtype}}" name="{{q.qid}}" ng-value="{{opt}}" ng-model="$parent.q.a">
            {{opt}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <h3>Your answer : {{q.a.toString()}}</h3>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: any errors in your console/firebug/devtools ?

Comment: do you have any sample data that we can work with?

Comment: may you paste the code of appenAnswer function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I cannot select any option from the radio buttons. It froze once I
>   click any of the option

I think that is because of you're doing a function call inside of your repeater:

```
<div ng-repeat="q in getCurrentSectionsQuestion().qs">
```

That is not a good practice since your `getCurrentSectionsQuestion()` function will be called several times due to `$digest` cycle and your application will have an error.

I suggest update your code as follows:

- Controller

```js
// Start code of your controller
activate();

function activate() {
  $scope.qs = vm.getCurrentSectionsQuestion().qs;
}

function getCurrentSectionsQuestion() {
  return {
    qs: [
      {
        qid: 'id',
        qtype: 'checkbox',
        options: [
          {
            selected: true,
            option: 'option A'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
}
```

- Markup

```html
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div ng-repeat="q in qs">
      <h2>{{q.q}}</h2>
      <ul ng-if="q.qtype == 'checkbox'">
        <li ng-repeat="option in q.options">
          <input type="{{q.qtype}}" name="{{q.qid}}" ng-value="{{option.selected}}" ng-model="option.selected"
                 ng-change="!option.selected || main.appendAnswer(q,option.option)"/>
          {{option.option}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul ng-if="q.qtype == 'radio'">
        <li ng-repeat="opt in q.options">
          <input type="{{q.qtype}}" name="{{q.qid}}" ng-value="{{opt}}" ng-model="$parent.q.a">
          {{opt}}
        </li>
      </ul>
      <h3>Your answer : {{q.a.toString()}}</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the value is of type string then this value should be writen inside quotes in the ng-value directive.

Example:

```
ng-value="'option-1-value'"
```

If the value isn't of type string you should check for any kind of directive cross interference or any other code misbehavior.